# Concept of overridding in java

Tags: java

A method in superclass works for all the subclasses in java....If a subclass has its own independent method, how can i make it work...

```
class  Polymorphism3 {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
            // note how these are all considered objects of type Animal by Java
            Animal[] a = new Animal[4];
            a[0] = new Mouse();
            a[1] = new Bird();
            a[2] = new Horse();
            a[3] = new Animal();            
            for (int i=0;i<4;i++) {
                a[i].pullTail();                
            }           

//...       


class Animal {
    public void pullTail() {
        System.out.println("I don't know what to say.");
    }
}

class Mouse extends Animal {
    public void pullTail() {
        System.out.println("fart");
    }
}

class Bird extends Animal {
    public void pullTail() {
        System.out.println("tweet");
    }

    public void fly() {
        System.out.println("flap");
    }
}

class Horse extends Animal {
    public void pullTail() {
        System.out.println("neigh");
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the question? You are correctly overriding the superclass methods...

Comment: `if (a[i] instanceOf Bird) ((Bird)a[i]).fly();`

Comment: Try removing the pullTail() method in one of your subclasses; then run your Polymorphism3.main() method.  That should clarify what's happening for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make it work if it's not declared in Animal.
The only way is to cast Animal to Bird such as

> ((Bird)a[1]).fly();

You can also call it from Bird's implementation of putTail.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked...now i got it only methods declared in Super class can work...in sub class

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. don't forget to mark an answer for this question.

Answer (score 1):

In case this is about not being able to instantiate the nested classes: you need an object of the enclosing class for that:

```
public class Polymorphism3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // note how these are all considered objects of type Animal by Java
        Animal[] a = new Animal[4];
        Polymorphism3 poly = new Polymorphism3();
        a[0] = poly.new Mouse();
        a[1] = poly.new Bird();
        a[2] = poly.new Horse();
        a[3] = poly.new Animal();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            a[i].pullTail();
        }
    }

    class Animal {
        public void pullTail() {
            System.out.println("I don't know what to say.");
        }
    }

    class Mouse extends Animal {
        public void pullTail() {
            System.out.println("fart");
        }
    }

    class Bird extends Animal {
        public void pullTail() {
            System.out.println("tweet");
        }

        public void fly() {
            System.out.println("flap");
        }
    }

    class Horse extends Animal {
        public void pullTail() {
            System.out.println("neigh");
        }
    }
}
```